# Overflow scrolling locks up on iOS Safari

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, safari

In my application I have section that has overflow scroll.
On safari for iOS the scrolling sometimes locks up.
This often happens when you're done editing the content of an input element, change option in a select element, or you tap on something outside of the section.

The locking behavior varies.
It will either not scroll the first time you try, and when you release and try again it will work, or it will just refuse to scroll, however many times you try.

The scroll will often become usable again if you open an input/select, or click on something inside the section.
I've tried working around this, by using `click()` on the `.edit-preview` whenever there is a click on something that might lock it up, but this doesn't seem to help. This does however work if you in the console use `click` on `.edit-preview` when it locks.

A lot of iOS specific fixes has been applied to fix various other bugs, but I've been unable to find a fix for this.

I've thrown it all into a JS Bin [here](http://output.jsbin.com/yirunejosi/).

I've experienced this on an iPhone 5 running iOS 9 beta version 3, and on an iPhone 6 plus running iOS 8.4.